# Google Spreadsheet How to turn a cell Grey after 24 hours have passed

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, time, conditional-formatting

I have a google spreadsheet with multiple rows, a few hundred. and in row "D" there are the dates the entry was added. i need that date to turn a color after 24 hours have passed. could use any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you already have dates added either via timestamp script or google form then enter conditional formatting and try:

```
=((NOW()-D1)>=1)*(D1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get it to work, the row i have all the Dates in is row D
The control Time (the sheet timer) is on B1.
how can i do it best?

Comment: @RollinGrim can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @player0 he said the dates were in column D...

Comment: @player0 The sheet is from my work, so can't share that unfortunately.
Here is what row "D" looks like https://i.imgur.com/AZ29rMV.png
And the Date on B1: https://i.imgur.com/z5sMVyh.png
if that helps

Comment: @MattKing I got a feeling it's not so simple to change A to D. could be more to it, that's why...

Comment: @RollinGrim answer updated

Comment: @player0 Doesn't seem to work either sadly

Comment: @RollinGrim copy-paste your scenario into: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a0fXiId1Cyo-pS1Mo5beZN8tvOPGNxRk-fA5tNicXOA/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 pasted the info simplified there. on sheet 2

Comment: @RollinGrim see the spreadsheet...

Comment: @player0 That did the trick, thank you so much!

Comment: @MattKing nvm, it was as simple as changing A1 to D6

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work, as soon as it becomes a new day, it turns the color, not after 24 hours. @player0 any other idea?

Comment: @RollinGrim your dates in D column do not contain time so the conditional formatting kicks in daily intervals. for more precision, you would need to include time within D column

Comment: @player0 Is there a way to add time in there, without it showing the time? so the data is there but doesn't show it?

Comment: @RollinGrim yes there is - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfCNj.png